# how to rescue two delimiters in php?

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhg2x.png)

hello, I want to save the ip in a variable, I have occurred to me by pinging with console.

And mark that I want the content that is in [ and ].

```
$host = 'google.es';
function sacarIP($host)
{
    exec("ping -n 1 $host", $output, $status);
    $ip = $output[1];
    return $ip;
}

echo sacarIP($host);
```

this brings me back to :

```
Haciendo ping a google.es [142.250.184.3] con 32 bytes de datos:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```php
$host = 'google.es';
function sacarIP($host)
{
    exec("ping -n 1 $host", $output, $status);
    preg_match('/\[\K[\d\.]+/', $output[1], $match);
    $ip = $match[0];
    return $ip;
}

echo sacarIP($host);
```